# Python how to update arrays and lists in loops

Tags: python, arrays, list

I got familiar of the fact that lists and numpy arrays have a strange behavior and there are a couple of posts that say why but they don't say anything about how to workaround the problem.

So, Python behaves like this:

```
`a = [1,2,3]`
`a`
`[1,2,3]`
`b=a`
`b=[1,2,3]`
`b`
`[1,2,3]`
`b[1] = 84`
`a`
`[1,84,3]`
```

What is the best workaround to achieve the following behavior?

```
`a = [1,2,3]`
`b=a`
`b[1] = 84`
`a`
`[1,2,3]`
```

Comment: **All** Python objects behave this way. This is not some strange detail of `list`s or `numpy.array`. If you want a copy, you have to explicitly make a copy. Whenever you do `a = b` then *a **is** b*

Comment: `b = a[:]`? Hard to say. Seems you want to modify `b` and leave `a` unchanged?

Comment: Also note, both `list`s and `numpy.ndarray`s have a convenient `.copy()` method. And also, it is very important to understand, **all python objects** behave this way, it is simply the semantics of the assignment statement in Python. Check out Ned Batcheder's [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) which explains in detail the semantics in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `b = a`, which takes a reference to the underlying object.

You want to write

```
b = list(a)
```

which will perform a shallow copy. Then you can mutate `a` or `b` independently of one another. For numpy this corresponds to `b = np.array(a)`. Or use `b = a.copy()`, whether `a` is a list or NP array.

Comment: does it work the same way with a numpy array?